# How to check if Javascript generator has exited?

Tags: javascript, generator, rhino, coroutine

I'm trying to implement a generator in Javascript and trying to determine whether or not my generator has completed.

There is a lot of conflicting information out there (I suppose since this is still a new feature).  Anyhow, I'm running this using [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino_documentation) 1.7 release 4 from within Java.  This is the syntax which seems to work:

```
function poem(foo)
{
    console.println("I think that I shall never see");
    var a = yield(foo);
    console.println("A poem as lovely as a tree");
    var b = yield(foo);
    console.println("And so I pushed it into the sea");
    var c = yield(foo);
    console.println("Hee hee hee hee");
}

var gen = poem();

gen.next();
console.println("is done " + gen.next(5).done);
```

This is different from the official documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/) and various other websites.  (The 'function*' keyword does not seem to work, and yield seems to expect parenthesis.)  I was also expecting the next() function to return an object with a 'value' and 'done' member, but I am getting 'undefined' instead.

I could catch the exception that is thrown when next() is called after the generator is finished, but this seems inelegant.  I also want to be more explicit that putting it inside a for() clause and having Javascript do the checking for me.

Is there a better way to check for when my generator finishes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) is the syntax for generators as defined in ECMAScript 6, which is a recent feature.

Rhino 1.7 is ancient, and also supports "generators", but its syntax is non-standard (back then, the `function*` syntax did not even exist!). You can find documentation for this old syntax at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Generators.3A_a_better_way_to_build_Iterators. When this old generator completes, an `StopIteration` exception is thrown. So you have to use try-catch to detect generator termination.

```
function legacyGenerator() {
    yield 1;
}
var gen = legacyGenerator();
gen.next(); // 1
gen.next(); // throws StopIteration
```

Comment: Thanks.  Would you have any suggestions for a more up-to-date javascript engine I could use in Java?  (Hopefully something that would work with both Oracle's SDK and Android's Davlik).

Comment: @kitfox The Rhino developers have moved to [Nashorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_%28JavaScript_engine%29), so you could take a look at that. Another option is to use the same JS engine as used in Google Chrome and Node.js, v8: [jav8](https://code.google.com/p/jav8/). I don't have any experience with either of these, you'll have to try and see whether they really match your expectations.